# ftp and sftp coexisting on one machine using windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp, sftp

Is it possible to have both ftp and sftp sites on one machine running Windows Server?  If I set up a secure sftp connection - do all ftp sites also on that machine require a secure connection?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. In fact, they are not related at all. FTP uses TCP port 21, SFTP is actually part of SSH and uses TCP 22.